# Accept any host header with ASP.Net WebAPI SelfHosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to accept any hostheader with ASP.Net WebApi eg:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(http://*:8080);
```

which I would expect to accept any host header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webapi appears to accept any host header (domain) for a self hosted service. For example if you bind

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(http://zzz:8080);
```

webapi will accept calls from

`http://aaa:8080` (assuming dns is pointing to the machine)

or

```
http://localhost:8080
```

This is not terribly intuitive